# How to work through Terraform resource error UnauthorizedOperation: This operation does not support shared VPCs

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc

I'm running a terraform .tf script to create aws_vpc_endpoint

Here is examply code

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "NewVPCEndpoint" {..}
```

However, upon invoking terraform apply, I am getting error

```
Error creating VPC Endpoint: UnauthorizedOperation: This operation does not support shared VPCs.
    status code: 403
```

What reason exactly am I getting this error?

I have tried the same exact .tf script in a different VPC and it worked fine. 
Is this a setting with the VPC itself? What setting might this be exactly?

With respect to the VPC and subnets, what are the prerequisite attributes/settings of the VPC/Subnets in order for

```
resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "NewVPCEndpoint"
```

To succeed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A VPC can be a [Shared VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-sharing.html) at which point it won't support deploying a VPC Endpoint Service:

> VPC sharing allows multiple AWS accounts to create their application resources, such as Amazon EC2 instances, Amazon Relational Database Service (RDS) databases, Amazon Redshift clusters, and AWS Lambda functions, into shared, centrally-managed Amazon Virtual Private Clouds (VPCs). In this model, the account that owns the VPC (owner) shares one or more subnets with other accounts (participants) that belong to the same organization from AWS Organizations. After a subnet is shared, the participants can view, create, modify, and delete their application resources in the subnets shared with them. Participants cannot view, modify, or delete resources that belong to other participants or the VPC owner.

The fix is to deploy a separate VPC (not shared) and set up VPC peering with the shared VPC. Then you can deploy the VPC Endpoint Service within the non-shared peered VPC and access it from the shared VPC from all participating accounts.

Comment: Im seeing something that looks to contradict this peering apporach "You have a VPC peering connection between VPC A and VPC B. VPC A also has a Site-to-Site VPN
connection or an AWS Direct Connect connection to a corporate network. Edge to edge routing is not
supported; you cannot use VPC A to extend the peering relationship to exist between VPC B and the
corporate network. For example, traffic from the corporate network can’t directly access VPC B by using
the VPN connection or the AWS Direct Connect connection to VPC A"

Comment: That's correct. That was not a part of this problem. On your other question, I'm trying to determine if a transit VPC will sort that out. Otherwise you'll need to deploy a proxy like haproxy or nginx in the shared VPC or do some IP-based TG hackery with an NLB to provide an application layer hop to avoid the transitive routing limitation.

Comment: Would the topic of how an on prem system interact with VPC endpoint be 3rd question you think?

Comment: No, I think it's fair game for your other question. You should revise that question quickly from "is it possible" to "how do I do it" though. I haven't found a viable solution, but hopefully someone will.

Comment: Why exactly do you think I should revise the question so quickly in that way? (Maybe you can post your response to this in the separate question to keep this thread consistent?)